# Python : Play mp3 before user login in linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a python file that needs to play an mp3 repeatedly on startup. The following is the code snippet.

```
while True:
    playsound.playsound('file.mp3')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I added the python path to the profile in `etc/profile` as follows, but the issue is the sound is not playing.
`/usr/bin/python3 /opt/play_music.py`

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this? Have you verified that the script is running at all? Have you verified that putting other things in `etc/profile` causes them to be executed successfully?

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes the script is running when I log in to any user. I know it is too much to ask for but I want the sound to be played on the login screen itself. The use case is I have a server machine in a remote area where no one will be there to manage, which need to play a mp3 on some event

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745933/execute-script-before-login) from askubuntu seems relevant, have you tried `/etc/rc.local`?